# Allow tag-searching to include results based on tag description

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

#### [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

It would be great if there were two different types of searches we can make when searching tags:

- **standard search** (status quo): search in tag names only
- **extended search**: search in tag names + tag descriptions
  That would make it easier to find some tags.

#### **Example use-case:**

I'll give some examples for aviation.SE:

- user doesn't know a certain technical term. Standard search for *"drone"* doesn't find anything. Searching *"drone"* in descriptions would find [unmanned-aerial-vehicle](/questions/tagged/unmanned-aerial-vehicle). Same for *"oxygen deprivation"* instead of [hypoxia](/questions/tagged/hypoxia).
- user wants to find a health-related tag, but doesn't know which one is used for that. *"Health"* doesn't yield any results in the standard search. Using the tag description search, the user would find [air-quality](/questions/tagged/air-quality).
- user wants to find ALL tags including a certain word like *"wings"* or *"radar"*.
  Standard search for *"radar"* finds [radar](/questions/tagged/radar), [flightradar24](/questions/tagged/flightradar24), [pesa-radar](/questions/tagged/pesa-radar), [online-radar](/questions/tagged/online-radar), but not [avionics](/questions/tagged/avionics)
- Also remember that for some users English is a foreign language. So the extended search is helpful for users with limited vocabulary.

(Tag synonyms may help in *some* of these situations, but certainly not in all)

Comment: Do you have an example of where this would be useful?

Comment: I don't understand the question. This is useful for any tag.

Comment: I don't understand your request.  What use case is there for searching descriptions?  Give us an example where this can provide some utility.

Comment: There are so many use cases that I have a hard time believing that you can't imagine any. It's like asking "why would a search be useful" ? Regardless, I have added some use cases to the RFE.

Comment: How would this be implemented? A specific operator to switch to tag description mode? If this were to be implemented, maybe it should include the tag wiki.

Comment: maybe a drop-down menu or radio buttons to choose between "search in tags only", "search in tags+description", "search in tags+description+ wiki" (the latter is possible via the SEDE query posted in the answer below).

Answer (score 9):

Until this feature is implemented, you can use the following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/945982/tag-names-wikis-excerpts-containing-certain-words) to search in tag names, tag descriptions ('excerpts') and tag wikis.

[image]

```sql
SELECT t.TagName, 'Tag', ''
  FROM Tags AS t
  WHERE t.TagName LIKE '%' + ##query:string## + '%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai

UNION ALL

SELECT t.TagName, 'Excerpt', p.Body
  FROM Tags AS t
  INNER JOIN Posts AS p
    ON p.Id = t.ExcerptPostId
  WHERE p.Body LIKE '%' + ##query:string## + '%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai

UNION ALL

SELECT t.TagName, 'Wiki', p.Body
  FROM Tags AS t
  INNER JOIN Posts AS p
    ON p.Id = t.WikiPostId
  WHERE p.Body LIKE '%' + ##query:string## + '%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai
```

Note that SEDE is updated once every week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: You might want to add `collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_ai ` to those `LIKE` clauses to make those searches case insensitive

Comment: Heh, I always forget about those...

Comment: Very helpful for the meanwhile. Thanks!